# Dojo tree nodes `not` expanded by default

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo

How do I make the DOJO root node not expand by default . For example look at [Making nodes expand by clicking on the label](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Tree-examples.html#id5) running code .

On running the source code `The Earth` is expanded by default . What dojo property should i set to have if closed by default .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change autoExpand to false

Change:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Tree" data-dojo-id="mytree" 
data-dojo-props="model: myModel, autoExpand: true"></div>
```

To:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Tree" data-dojo-id="mytree"
        data-dojo-props="model: myModel, autoExpand: false"></div>
```